# Card container display: flex not working due to margin size issues

Tags: html, css, margin

I have run into this problem I just can't fix and I believe it is due to the margin being so big.

The problem is that I would like 3 images beside each other on my website but they don't want to be next to each other because I believe the margin is so big.

I am very new to coding sorry if I'm missing something.

```css
body {
  background-color: AliceBlue;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.arms {
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 300px;
}

#imgarms {
  left: 300px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 320px;
  border: 2px solid #F0FFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}

a:hover {
  border-color: black;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: -30;
}

#title {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 0;
}

.abs {
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 300px;
}

.shoulders {
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 300px;
}

.back {
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 300px;
}

.legs {
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 300px;
}

.chest {
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 300px;
}

.cardContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="title" class="title">
    <img id="title" class="title" src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/4e936b48ef16b9730de36cbbaec1c6c1e4988efc-5ea104f02cc0c3264f51231e.png" alt="title" />

  </div>

  <div class="cardContainer">
    <a href="arms.html#scBarnowl">
      <article class="card">
        <img src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/8c41ed921e47afbbd3c097a06f8d44186fabf24e-5e9faf172cc0c3264f47ec6b.png" class="arms">

      </article>

    </a>
    <a href="abs.html#scBarnowl">
      <article class="card">
        <img src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/8a1dbd5f8fcbc27772e44b9edadb3eea4d5f8e3d-5e9faf172cc0c3264f47ec6a.png" class="abs">

      </article>

    </a>
    <a href="shoulders.html#scBarnowl">
      <article class="card">
        <img src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/6ba09699551ac1bc979673bbf99fee75b4064d10-5e9faf182cc0c3264f47ec71.png" class="shoulders">

      </article>
    </a>

    <a href="back.html#scBarnowl">
      <article class="card">
        <img src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/a6776f95e6b7868be91d5aa0e89710e64e62fff8-5e9faf182cc0c3264f47ec6d.png" class="back">

      </article>

    </a>

    <a href="legs.html#scBarnowl">
      <article class="card">
        <img src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/b628c0bca25058c3dac2cffcaff1ae4552522e7e-5e9faf182cc0c3264f47ec70.png" class="legs">

      </article>

    </a>
    <a href="chest.html#scBarnowl">
      <article class="card">
        <img src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/373f3cbc6207fa4f67b4bcccb42f3b344c3fd10b-5e9faf182cc0c3264f47ec6f.png" class="chest">

      </article>

    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are required to post the code to the question itself and not an offsite link. Use the stack snippet feature to add HTML/CSS. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to stick the images on your main page together. This is caused by the margins on your `a` tags together with the `justify-content: space-around;` of the `.cardContainer`.

To make the images stick together, **remove the margins in the `a` and change `justify-content: center` in `.cardContainer`**.

Your code with my modifications is added below.

When you use `justify-content: space-around;` the remaining space that elements can't take, will be spread around the items. This is displayed in the image (and snippet) below. This has space between items even though there is no margin.

```css
.item{
  background: lightgreen;
  border: 2px solid darkgreen;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper{
  justify-content: space-around;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 300px;
  width: 390px;
  padding: 10px;
  
  background: lightblue;
  border: 2px dotted darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

[image: space-around]

When you use `justify-content: center;` instead, the remaining space where elements can't go will only be added to the left and to the right of the content. So it gets centered and there will be no space inbetween the items (except if you set a margin or padding).

```css
.item{
  background: lightgreen;
  border: 2px solid darkgreen;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper{
  justify-content: center;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 300px;
  width: 390px;
  padding: 10px;
  
  background: lightblue;
  border: 2px dotted darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

[image: center]

Your modified code:

```css
body {
  background-color: orange;
}
body {
  background-color: AliceBlue;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
nav ul {
    background-color: tomato;
}
.arms {
  
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 300px;
}

#imgarms {
  left: 300px;
}
a {
   display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 320px;
    border: 2px solid #F0FFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 
    /* remove this padding to make the images really stick together */
    padding: 10px;
    z-index:10;
}
a:hover {
    border-color: black;
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    left:-20px;
}
.title {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left:-30;
}

#title {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 0;
}

.abs {
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 300px;
}
.shoulders {
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 300px;
}

.back {
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 300px;
}

.legs {
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 300px;
}

.chest {
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: 300px;
}

.cardContainer {
   
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
}













/**********************************
This section is for styling tables
***********************************/
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid HoneyDew;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
  background-color: PaleTurquoise;
}
th, td {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
th {
  color: purple;
}
td {
  color: purple;
}
/********************************/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Get Fit</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 </head>
 <body>
   <header>
     
   </header>
   <main>
    <div id="title" class="title">
    <img id="title" class="title" src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/4e936b48ef16b9730de36cbbaec1c6c1e4988efc-5ea104f02cc0c3264f51231e.png" alt="title" />
  
</div>  
    
  <div class="cardContainer">   
    <a href="arms.html#scBarnowl"> 
    <article class="card">
    <img src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/8c41ed921e47afbbd3c097a06f8d44186fabf24e-5e9faf172cc0c3264f47ec6b.png" class="arms">
  
</article>

</a>
  <a href="abs.html#scBarnowl"> 
    <article class="card">
    <img src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/8a1dbd5f8fcbc27772e44b9edadb3eea4d5f8e3d-5e9faf172cc0c3264f47ec6a.png" class="abs">
  
</article>

</a>
  <a href="shoulders.html#scBarnowl"> 
    <article class="card">
    <img src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/6ba09699551ac1bc979673bbf99fee75b4064d10-5e9faf182cc0c3264f47ec71.png" class="shoulders">
  
</article>
</a>

<a href="back.html#scBarnowl"> 
    <article class="card">
    <img src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/a6776f95e6b7868be91d5aa0e89710e64e62fff8-5e9faf182cc0c3264f47ec6d.png" class="back">
  
</article>

</a>

<a href="legs.html#scBarnowl"> 
    <article class="card">
    <img src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/b628c0bca25058c3dac2cffcaff1ae4552522e7e-5e9faf182cc0c3264f47ec70.png" class="legs">
  
</article>

</a>
<a href="chest.html#scBarnowl"> 
    <article class="card">
    <img src="https://trinket-user-assets.trinket.io/373f3cbc6207fa4f67b4bcccb42f3b344c3fd10b-5e9faf182cc0c3264f47ec6f.png" class="chest">
  
</article>

</a>


  </div>
   </main>
   <footer>
     
   </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```